# c# Assigning the same result to different objects with Switch

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I have a switch case structure like this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"title", "title.val"},
    {"phone", "phone.val"},
    {"address", "address.val"},
    {"e_mail", "email.val"},
    {"work_phone", "workphone.val"}
};

foreach (var p in dict)
{
    string str = ___ANY_METHOD___(p.Value);
    
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    {
        switch (p.Key)
        {
            case "title":
                _trp.Name = str;
                break;
            case "phone":
                _trp.Phone = str;
                break;
            case "address":
                _trp.Address = str;
                break;
            case "e_mail":
                _trp.Email = str;
                break;
            case "work_phone":
                _trp.WorkPhone = str;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Due to the difference in the incoming values, there is no error in the switch case structure and the program runs smoothly as it is. But as it stands, the code snippet looks pretty ugly. Is there a better way to assign the same value to `prs.Name, prs.Phone, prs.Address, prs.Email, prs.WorkPhone` objects in the switch case structure?

Comment: if your p.key.toStrin() same with filedName , you can just use reflection. like 'FieldInfo' to set value

Comment: but it's like XY problem , can you show what context that you need use string key. and why assign in `_obj[0] ` ?

Comment: @TimChang - I think it is not matter what happens. After all, I'm passing the element value of the dictionary through a method. The method is returning me different values based on the dictionary key. I can assign these values to the same variable. The result is as above. I'm just wondering if there is a better way to write the switch statement above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine the object property name dynamically](/q/12251739/90527), [Refer Object's Property by string](/q/23343569/90527)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just set the properties and drop the switch?

```cs
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dict["title"])
    _trp.Name = ___ANY_METHOD___(dict["title"])[0].ToString();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dict["phone"])
    _trp.Phone = ___ANY_METHOD___(dict["phone"])[0].ToString();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dict["address"])
    _trp.Address = ___ANY_METHOD___(dict["address"])[0].ToString();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dict["e_mail"])
    _trp.Email = ___ANY_METHOD___(dict["e_mail"])[0].ToString();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dict["work_phone"])
    _trp.WorkPhone = ___ANY_METHOD___(dict["work_phone"])[0].ToString();
```

It requires that ANY METHOD has no side-effects.

Comment: Hımm, sometimes you get stuck in a thought and nothing else comes to mind. I always had switch case statement in mind.

Comment: Interestingly, when you do this, ReSharper gives a switch case statement suggestion. So I must be oriented towards switch case too.

Answer (score -1):

Both Are Correct

```
case "title" or "phone" or "address" or "e_mail" or "work_phone":

case "title","phone","address","e_mail","work_phone":
```

Your Answer is :

```
switch (p.Key)
{
    case "title" or "phone" or "address" or "e_mail" or "work_phone":
        prs.Name = prs.Phone =  prs.Address = prs.Email = prs.WorkPhone = _obj[0].ToString();
        break;
.
.
.
//if you have other cases

}
```

Comment: you are overwriting all properties of the object, i think this is not what was expected

Comment: @likquietly - Absolutely, this is overwriting all properties of the object. So I edited my question to avoid misunderstandings.